# JHipster 8.1.0 with Oracle fails IT

Tags: jhipster, testcontainers

I'm still hoping that I can address this myself with a simple change, but I'm missing something...

We have an Oracle backend so building `applicationType microservice` with `devDatabaseType oracle` is desired.

Something appears to have changed in TestContainers, or something is off with JHipster 8.1.0. I can run `jhipster` and select `PostgreSQL` for my dev and production database and have no issue running `./mvnw verify`.

I can run the same and select `Oracle` and BOOM. The IT tests fail outright. Won't even start.

I've tried changing the `dependency` to `oracle-free` (allegedly the replacement for `oracle-xe`. I've played with the `testdev` profile using the TestContainer JDBC URL, e.g., `jdbc:tc:...` [see Using Oracle](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#using-oracle).

Nothing.

Yes, I've looked for `com.company.api.config.TestContainer`. It's not there. But it's not there using PostgreSQL either. This seems to be something that TestContainer manages.

Context:

- JHipster 8.1.0
- Node 18.19.0
- Java 17
- `.yo-rc.json` below

```json
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "authenticationType": "oauth2",
    "baseName": "MyCompanyAPI",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "cacheProvider": "redis",
    "clientFramework": "no",
    "clientTestFrameworks": null,
    "clientTheme": null,
    "creationTimestamp": 1706145495217,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "oracle",
    "enableGradleEnterprise": null,
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": true,
    "enableTranslation": false,
    "entities": [],
    "feignClient": true,
    "gradleEnterpriseHost": null,
    "jhipsterVersion": "8.1.0",
    "jwtSecretKey": "ZRWjMjUzZDEwN2MlZTMwMmQxN2YwYTQ2NTQ4ODRhMWM0YWZlMTA2MDcxZDghDNwkNWM1Zjc2ZGZiZTYzNzZmFGU0MWU3MjJmMmJmODYwZjYwNDBhYWUyMjMzMDc5ZjgzNWYjMmMyMjQ1MGFiZmQ2ZTFlNAalMzk5YWY5NzhlYWU=",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "microfrontend": null,
    "microfrontends": [],
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "packageName": "com.company.mycompanyapi",
    "prodDatabaseType": "oracle",
    "reactive": false,
    "searchEngine": false,
    "serverPort": 8081,
    "serverSideOptions": ["enableSwaggerCodegen:true"],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "consul",
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "testFrameworks": ["gatling"],
    "websocket": false,
    "withAdminUi": null
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Log follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 7, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.421 s <<< FAILURE! -- in com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT
com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeOffsetTimeWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnConfiguredTimeZoneAccordingToHis1stJan1970Value -- Time elapsed: 0.003 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1fb00a6d testClass = com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT, locations = [], classes = [com.company.api.MyCompanyApiApp, com.company.api.config.AsyncSyncConfiguration, com.company.api.config.TestSecurityConfiguration], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [com.company.api.config.SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$550/0x00000008002a4498@2ceca2ef, com.company.api.config.RedisTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$551/0x00000008002a46c0@3b42121d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@20ead579, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@17fede14, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@41d16cc3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@f0a66bd, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ef248a67], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.api.config.TestContainer
    at com.company.api.config.SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.lambda$createContextCustomizer$0(SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:442)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:626)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.api.config.TestContainer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at com.company.api.config.SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.lambda$createContextCustomizer$0(SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.java:30)
    ... 30 more

com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeLocalDateWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredWithoutTransformation -- Time elapsed: 0 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1fb00a6d testClass = com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT, locations = [], classes = [com.company.api.MyCompanyApiApp, com.company.api.config.AsyncSyncConfiguration, com.company.api.config.TestSecurityConfiguration], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [com.company.api.config.SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$550/0x00000008002a4498@2ceca2ef, com.company.api.config.RedisTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$551/0x00000008002a46c0@3b42121d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@20ead579, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@17fede14, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@41d16cc3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@f0a66bd, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ef248a67], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeInstantWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnConfiguredTimeZone -- Time elapsed: 0 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1fb00a6d testClass = com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT, locations = [], classes = [com.company.api.MyCompanyApiApp, com.company.api.config.AsyncSyncConfiguration, com.company.api.config.TestSecurityConfiguration], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [com.company.api.config.SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$550/0x00000008002a4498@2ceca2ef, com.company.api.config.RedisTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$551/0x00000008002a46c0@3b42121d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@20ead579, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@17fede14, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@41d16cc3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@f0a66bd, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ef248a67], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeZoneDateTimeWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnConfiguredTimeZone -- Time elapsed: 0.001 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1fb00a6d testClass = com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT, locations = [], classes = [com.company.api.MyCompanyApiApp, com.company.api.config.AsyncSyncConfiguration, com.company.api.config.TestSecurityConfiguration], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [com.company.api.config.SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$550/0x00000008002a4498@2ceca2ef, com.company.api.config.RedisTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$551/0x00000008002a46c0@3b42121d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@20ead579, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@17fede14, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@41d16cc3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@f0a66bd, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ef248a67], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeOffsetDateTimeWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnConfiguredTimeZone -- Time elapsed: 0 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1fb00a6d testClass = com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT, locations = [], classes = [com.company.api.MyCompanyApiApp, com.company.api.config.AsyncSyncConfiguration, com.company.api.config.TestSecurityConfiguration], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [com.company.api.config.SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$550/0x00000008002a4498@2ceca2ef, com.company.api.config.RedisTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$551/0x00000008002a46c0@3b42121d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@20ead579, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@17fede14, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@41d16cc3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@f0a66bd, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ef248a67], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeLocalDateTimeWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnConfiguredTimeZone -- Time elapsed: 0 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1fb00a6d testClass = com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT, locations = [], classes = [com.company.api.MyCompanyApiApp, com.company.api.config.AsyncSyncConfiguration, com.company.api.config.TestSecurityConfiguration], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [com.company.api.config.SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$550/0x00000008002a4498@2ceca2ef, com.company.api.config.RedisTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$551/0x00000008002a46c0@3b42121d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@20ead579, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@17fede14, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@41d16cc3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@f0a66bd, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ef248a67], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT.storeLocalTimeWithZoneIdConfigShouldBeStoredOnConfiguredTimeZoneAccordingToHis1stJan1970Value -- Time elapsed: 0 s <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@1fb00a6d testClass = com.company.api.config.timezone.HibernateTimeZoneIT, locations = [], classes = [com.company.api.MyCompanyApiApp, com.company.api.config.AsyncSyncConfiguration, com.company.api.config.TestSecurityConfiguration], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [com.company.api.config.SqlTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$550/0x00000008002a4498@2ceca2ef, com.company.api.config.RedisTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory$$Lambda$551/0x00000008002a46c0@3b42121d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@20ead579, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@17fede14, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@41d16cc3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@f0a66bd, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ef248a67], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
... trimmed for character limit...
```

Comment: The `jwtSecretKey` has been replaced and is not the secret generated. It's throw away anyway.